# Simple runtime call in Rust

Tags: rust, subxt, runtime-api

I am building a somewhat generic client for Substrate-based chains in Rust using the `subxt` crate. To learn about runtime calls, my goal was to call the `core.version` runtime API directly using the RPC endpoint `state_call`.

Internally `subxt` uses a special RPC endpoint `state_getRuntimeVersion`, but that just gets redirected to the runtime at the specific block anyways:

```rust
    /// Fetch the runtime version
    pub async fn runtime_version(
        &self,
        at: Option<T::Hash>,
    ) -> Result<RuntimeVersion, BasicError> {
        let params = rpc_params![at];
        let version = self
            .client
            .request("state_getRuntimeVersion", params)
            .await?;
        Ok(version)
    }
```

This was my try to make the runtime call directly:

```rust
    let version: subxt::rpc::RuntimeVersion = rpc_client
        .rpc()
        .client
        .request("state_call", rpc_params!["core.version", ""])
        .await
        .unwrap();
```

But it just errs out with `Exported method core.version is not found`. How can I make this call work?

Comment: Opposed to polkadot.js, found out  the method name needs to be `Core_version`. Still, decoding the `RuntimeVersion` from the returned JSON string and encoding the call parameters and the blockhash still seems to be missing an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've found this out, but for others: In chrome you can run polkadot js and then inspect the webpage and switch over to the network tab. From there if you click on `ws` to filter to the websockets you can see the request and response from the UI for any call whether that's a state query, rpc call, runtime call or submitting an extrinsic.

Here's the request you can see on the wire:

```json
{
  "id":157,
  "jsonrpc":"2.0",
  "method":"state_call",
  "params":["Core_version","0x"]
}
```

The result is

```json
{
  "jsonrpc":"2.0",
  "result":"0x20706f6c6b61646f743c7061726974792d706f6c6b61646f74000000000e2400000000000038df6acb689907609b0400000037e397fc7c91f5e40100000040fe3ad401f8959a06000000d2bc9897eed08f1503000000f78b278be53f454c02000000af2c0297a23e6d3d0200000049eaaf1b548a0cb00100000091d5df18b0d2cf5801000000ed99c5acb25eedf503000000cbca25e39f14238702000000687ad44ad37f03c201000000ab3c0572291feb8b01000000bc9d89904f5b923f0100000037c8bb1350a9a2a8010000000c00000000",
  "id":157
}
```

and we can see in polkadot js this decodes to

```json
{
  "specName": "polkadot",
  "implName": "parity-polkadot",
  "authoringVersion": 0,
  "specVersion": 9230,
  "implVersion": 0,
  "apis": [
    [ "0xdf6acb689907609b", 4 ],
    [ "0x37e397fc7c91f5e4", 1 ],
    [ "0x40fe3ad401f8959a", 6 ],
    [ "0xd2bc9897eed08f15", 3 ],
    [ "0xf78b278be53f454c", 2 ],
    [ "0xaf2c0297a23e6d3d", 2 ],
    [ "0x49eaaf1b548a0cb0", 1 ],
    [ "0x91d5df18b0d2cf58", 1 ],
    [ "0xed99c5acb25eedf5", 3 ],
    [ "0xcbca25e39f142387", 2 ],
    [ "0x687ad44ad37f03c2", 1 ],
    [ "0xab3c0572291feb8b", 1 ],
    [ "0xbc9d89904f5b923f", 1 ],
    [ "0x37c8bb1350a9a2a8", 1 ]
  ],
  "transactionVersion": 12,
  "stateVersion": 0
}
```

polkadot in hex is 70 6f 6c 6b 61 64 6f 74 so that gives you a pretty good steer on the decoding front. The code is [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/5597a93a8c8b1ab578693c68549e3ce1902f3eaf/primitives/version/src/lib.rs#L228) to decode it. The 0x20 prefix will be a `Compact<u32>` saying what the string length is. But you should be able to call `sp_version::RuntimeVersion::decode(&mut &bytes[..])` to decode it all in one go.

Comment: A slight inconvenience seems to be that neither `sp-api` nor `sp-version` is kept up-to-date on `crates.io`, neither `subxt` reexports it like is does with `sp-runtime` or `sp-core`. I guess the thinking was you depend on the client code of a single chain anyways, and that could reexport the correct versions of these crates?